# Converting GUID into NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, guid, nsnumber

I want to convert a `string` with a guid into a `NSNumber` or any other numeric datatype able to handle a guid.

I only found ways to convert it into `double / int` etc what doesn't meet my requirements.

Comment: NSNumber is a way of "boxing" primitive data types into an object and a 128-bit UUID cannot be represented using a primitive data type.  So back to the drawing board...

Comment: if you can convert it to int then you can use `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` to convert the int to NSNumber

Comment: What numerical data type are you thinking of that could cope with 128 bit these days? 128 Bit sums up to 16 Byte. Better go a step back and ask yourself what you aim to achieve and then think about alternative solutinons. NSData or NSString or an array of 16 char, 8 2-byte-integers or 4 4-byte-integers.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I wrote a `UUID` class myself, that wraps `uuid_generate()` and family.  Works just fine.

Comment: You can make an array of NSNumbers...